# How Can I make sprite sheet with only one image in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-sheet

Hello dear developers,

I have a picture as above. I just want to use one image and I want to show the corresponding car image according to the selected angle.

As seen in the bottom photo, for example, when there is an angle of 30 degrees, I want to get the view that is equivalent to 30 degrees.

Thanks,

Example images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you have 24 photos, you can probably split your problem in: "How to have a function that receives a degree, and outputs a number from 0 to 23" (→ do a ratio). Then, after you have a number from 0 to 23, do a simple division with module 6 (→ your row length) to have x and y.

Comment: @ValerioBozz There is no problem in getting the angle. But I don't know how to split a single photo.

Comment: If you need a code example you may need to at least mention a framework or programming language to be used. Otherwise people can only help with generical math tips.

Comment: @ValerioBozz Thanks for the info but I wrote it in the question title (Swift)